# Cannot log terminal output using complex cat command, error "input file is output file"

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script having the below command and then log the output to a file:

```
cat "$(ls -rt | tail -n1)" >> Run.log
```

but getting an error,

```
Run.log : input file is the output file
```

This command works fine directly in the terminal and prints the latest file output in the current directory.

What am I doing wrong in the shell script?

Comment: what does `ls -rt | tail -n1` return when run in the terminal? what does it return when run in the script?

Comment: What if the latest file in the current directory is `Run.log`?

Comment: ls -rt | tail -n1 ---  gives the name of the last modified file in the directory

Comment: @JohnKugelman -  I think you are correct , maybe that is the last file in the directory